# Javascript return value. Sanity about to leave the building

Tags: javascript

Ok, this one should in theory be as simple as it gets - but I've trawled the code over and over, googled, etc etc. I can find nothing wrong. And yet, there seemingly is.

Given the code below, I call "WaitForMars". I get an alert: "GMS Data: SOMESTUFF". Then another alert: "Process found". Then another alert: "GMS: undefined".

So the jQuery in "getMarsStatus" is returning some data - hence Process found. Therefore, getMarsStatus SHOULD be returning 1, setting my GMS variable in WaitForMars to 1. But it's undefined?!?

Any help would be greatly received, while I still have hair left... :)

```
function getMarsStatus()
{
    var request = $.get("getMarsStatus"); // routes to a call to checkForMarsProcess
    request.success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert("GMS Data: " + data)
        if (data == "") {
            alert("NO Process found");
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            alert("Process found");
            return 1;
        }
    })
    request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert ("GMS err: " + errorThrown);
    })
}

function WaitForMars()
{
    var GMS = getMarsStatus();
    alert("GMS: " + GMS);
    while (GMS == 1)
    {
        alert("Waiting 3s");
        sleep(3000);
        getMarsLog();
        GMS = getMarsStatus()

    }
}
```

Comment: Because it is asynchronous!

Comment: You'll need a callback in `getMarsStatus`. You're returning 0 or 1 from your callback to `$.get` you're not returning it from `getMarsStatus` - you're not returning anything from that, hence the `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks Rob :) It's been a learning filled couple of weeks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getMarsStatus returns delayed return, so basically you end you function, return undefined and only then your success is fired. Use callback function instead.

Comment: I wanted to - but SO wouldn't let me for a few mins, and I had to go to a meeting ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
function getMarsStatus()
{
    var request = $.get("getMarsStatus"); // routes to a call to checkForMarsProcess
    request.success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert("GMS Data: " + data)
        if (data == "") {
            alert("NO Process found");
        } else {
            // Process found
            WaitForMars(1);
        }
    })
    request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert ("GMS err: " + errorThrown);
    })
}

function WaitForMars(GMS)
{
    alert("GMS: " + GMS);
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("Waiting 3s");
        getMarsLog();
        getMarsStatus();
    }, 3000);

}

getMarsStatus();
```

Comment: Thanks Uriy -  It's at moments like this I wish I could accept two answers - but Justinas did get in there first with the reason ;) Much appreciated anyway, thank you :)